# Find matching entity based on dynamic comparisons

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm not sure the subject actually makes sense but I wasn't sure how to word it. Here's the set up: I have an `Item`, which has many `ItemLogic`, each of which has one `Field`. Each `Item` has, say, 25 `ItemLogic` entities. The logic determines whether that `Item` matches the given input from the form. For instance, `Field X has a value greater than A` and `Field Y has a value equal to B` and so on for each of the 25 fields.

In the current version of the app, all related entities are queried out and looped over, returning the first matching Item where all the ItemLogic were `true`. It's a bit more expensive, but simple code, and there were never that many Items to look at. Until now.

Now the app needs to filter 3000 Items to find a match. The previous query had at least two joins and takes about 45 seconds on our SQL instance. This is far too long.

A stored procedure seems a natural fit, but here's the catch: the data is dynamic for each set of Items, it comes in as a string value and often needs to be cast as a different type (DateTime or int most commonly) to perform the actual comparisons, and some logic is ignored rather than compared. That's a lot of extra overhead in a stored procedure, at least that's how it strikes me.

Alternately, I could chunk the data, but that doesn't save much for the poor bloke trying to match the last Item in the collection.

What are some approaches that could be taken to speed up the match?

Schema and some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemLogic](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FieldId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Comparison] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fields](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [int] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Fields] (Value, Type) VALUES ('abc', 0), ('def', 0), ('123', 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Items] (Name) VALUES ('Item 1'), ('Item 2'), ('Item 3')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ItemLogic] (ItemId, FieldId, Value, Comparison) VALUES (1, 1, 'xyz', 1), (1, 2, 'qrs', 1), (1, 3, '200', 0), (2, 1, 'abc', 1), (2, 2, 'xyz', 1), (2, 3, '123', 2), (3, 1, 'abc', 1), (3, 2, 'def', 1), (3, 2, '100', 0)
```

For the `Comparison` field, it is an enum matching: 0 = Greater Than, 1 = Equal, 2 = Ignore. For the `Type` field, it is an enum matching: 0 = string, 1 = int.

The expected result of the above match should be that `Item 3` is returned.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be most helpful.  Particulary how the search strings are passed.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I will work on some sample data. Right now nothing is 
"passed". A JSON request comes in with the fields, and I then have the collection of `Field`s with a string value and the whole thing is looped over.

Comment: Just a small sample would help with the visualization

Comment: @JohnCappelletti added

Comment: `returning the first matching Item where all the ItemLogic were true` - **first** is undeterministic unless you specify what ordering you want. Even clustered indexes do not guarantee ordered results.

Comment: Why Entity Framework (Core) tag? All I see is DDL / SQL, while in EF we work with models.

Comment: @Peter B - the Items have a `Sequence` field and are sorted by that, so it's not undeterministic. But yes, I left that out of my question as I was more interested in the approach to matching the logic.

Comment: @IvanStoev - the code uses EF Core so I tagged that, but in the end I'm not sure it's actually relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never be fast. However here is the most simple and compact solution I can imagine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    Items
WHERE 
    Id NOT IN (
        SELECT IL.ItemId
        FROM
            Fields F
            INNER JOIN ItemLogic IL
                ON F.Id = IL.FieldId
        WHERE
            NOT (
                IL.Comparison = 2 -- Ignore
                OR
                F.Type = 0 AND ( -- string types
                    IL.Comparison = 0 AND F.Value > IL.Value
                    OR 
                    IL.Comparison = 1 AND F.Value = IL.Value
                )
                OR
                F.Type = 1 AND ( -- integer types
                    IL.Comparison = 0 AND TRY_CAST(F.Value AS int) > TRY_CAST(IL.Value AS int)
                    OR 
                    IL.Comparison = 1 AND TRY_CAST(F.Value AS int) = TRY_CAST(IL.Value AS int)
                )
            )
        )
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a run tomorrow and see the results. I'm not expecting instantaneous, but It seems like I should be able to leverage SQL smarter.

Comment: After you try doing as mentioned above, you might try breaking it down even more - replace the OR's that are in the WHERE NOT part of the statement with UNION's. This way, if I see it right, you'd have 5 similar statements with different WHERE NOT part of the queries and you'd use UNION to merge the results. This should improve the performance further.

Comment: @MK_. In this case, splitting or's and union all won't improve performance, it will be worse.

Comment: @JesúsLópez - Splitting them because of F.Value and IL.Value should give better performance. I was mistaken, in splitting by the fixed value you're correct.

Comment: This answer provided the fastest matching. Thanks!

Comment: @NathanLoding, I'm glad to see I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case statements to perform the actual matching of fields based on your logic. Then simply count the number of matches and compare it with the number of fields to be matched. The following example demonstrates:

```
WITH CTE_TypedFieldValues
AS
(   -- First unpivot fields by data type and convert to typed value
    SELECT   [Id]
            ,[DataType]
            ,[0] AS [ValueString]
            ,CONVERT(INT, [1]) AS [ValueInt] 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT   [Id]
                ,[Value]
                ,[Type] AS [DataType]
                ,[Type]
        FROM dbo.Fields
    ) AS [FieldsSource]
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([Value])
        FOR [Type] IN ([0], [1])
    ) AS [FieldTyped]
), 
CTE_Compare
AS
(
    SELECT       [IL].[ItemId]
                ,[IL].[FieldId]
                ,[FV].[DataType]
                ,[IL].[Value] AS [LogicValue]
                ,[IL].[Comparison]
                ,[FV].[ValueString]
                ,[FV].[ValueInt]
                ,(
                    CASE 
                        WHEN [FV].[DataType]  = 0 THEN -- If data types are strings then use [ValueString] column for comparison
                            CASE 
                                WHEN [IL].[Comparison] = 0 THEN     -- Perform greater than comparison, if condition is met then flag as matched.
                                    CASE WHEN [FV].[ValueString] > [IL].[Value] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                                WHEN [IL].[Comparison] = 1 THEN     -- Perform greater than comparison, if condition is met then flag as matched.
                                    CASE WHEN  [FV].[ValueString] = [IL].[Value] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                            END
                        WHEN [FV].[DataType]  =  1 THEN -- If data types are integers then use [ValueInt] column for comparison
                            CASE 
                                WHEN [IL].[Comparison] = 0 THEN 
                                    CASE WHEN [FV].[ValueInt]  > CAST([IL].[Value] AS INT) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                                WHEN [IL].[Comparison] = 1 THEN
                                    CASE WHEN [FV].[ValueInt] = CAST([IL].[Value] AS INT) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                            END
                    END
                ) [Match]

    FROM        [dbo].[ItemLogic] [IL]
    INNER JOIN  CTE_TypedFieldValues [FV] ON [IL].FieldId = [FV].[Id]
    WHERE       Comparison < 2 -- Filter out fields marked as ignored.
)
SELECT      ItemId
            ,COUNT([FieldId]) AS [ExpectedMatches]
            ,SUM([Match]) AS [ActualMatches]
FROM        CTE_Compare
GROUP BY    ItemId
HAVING      COUNT([FieldId]) = SUM([Match]) -- Only return ItemIDs where the number matched fields is equal to the number of expected matches.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the use of Expected vs Actual matches. Since each Item may have a different number of expected fields - for instance, Item A may have Fields 1, 2, and 3 ignored, but Item B only has Field 3 ignored.

Comment: @NathanLoding ignored fields simply gets filtered out since they are not needed for comparison. That is the ‘comparison < 2’ where clause.  Your expected match count the number of fields that has some sort of comparison defined. The actual match count is the number of fields that has met the defined match condition. If both these numbers are the same then all conditions for a match would have been satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest different approach, i.e. separate logic: querying data will be done in SQL and all conversion and check I would do in the application. The logic wold be:

1. Get all `Items`, that need to be checked.
2. Loop throguh all `Items` (when match is found, break the loop). On each iteration, query related `ItemLogic` and `Field`. Do conversions and checks, which should be more efficient than in SQL (also, `select` queries will be executed in no time, since you will limit your query result to one item at a time).

Executing multiple queries might seem exepnsive, but if you do it within one connection (in .NET there's connection pooling, so you wouldn't even worry about that), it should be faster.

Comment: I tested this approach before posting my question. The times that the matched Item is more than halfway through (I don't have an exact percentage), the overall process is longer; so the problem of speed is only solved some of the time. I'd rather have a consistent experience.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can retrieve all records and apply the rules on the memory. You can also try to store related records on the memory as well.

Comment: That is how the app currently works - it queries everything out, loops them, breaks the loop when the first match is found. The issue is that the initial query to grab all items and logic takes far too long.